# Remove arrow from time input in Android Chrome

Tags: android, html, google-chrome

I'm working on a webapp also to be used on small smartphones. One of the fields in a form is a time input field. I need this to be nice and small and a width of 55px does the trick on most OS and browsers.

```
<input type="time" value="12:34" style="width:55px">
```

However, Android Chrome always has some additional space:
[image: Android Chrom time imput]

When I add a "-webkit-appearance: none" the arrow disapears but leaves an empty space, so my time is still chopped off.
I have tried many controlls and those solved other issues in Chrome on my desktop (spin-button, clear-button, etc). But nothing I found removes it in Android Chrome.

Does anyone know how to get rid of this?
Tested on Android 5 and 6 both with Chrome 56.

Quick example https://jsfiddle.net/nm97kvk0/2/

Answer (score 1):

I tried this

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
```

with

```
::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
::-webkit-clear-button,
::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator
```

It works with desktop. There is no arrow in Android Chrome, but background under arrow is still there and overlay part of last digit(

Desktop Chrome
[image: Desktop Chrome]

Android Chrome
[image: Android Chrome]

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, exactly what I found. So almost 1,5 year later still no solution. And that for a browser maintained by the people that also maintain Android. Kinda strange.